# Why is a strange class being applied to certain images on my site?

Tags: html, css, image, class

I built a simple site as part of teaching myself HTML, CSS and JQuery. You can see it here: http://davideyre.co.uk

It was working fine for a while, but now in the 'contact' div several of the images have disappeared. The blue email image remains and the mouseover works to switch to the black email image, but the Twitter, LinkedIn and Google images are not displaying at all.

When I looked at them using the Inspect Element plugin on Firefox, it appears that an img class is being applied to these three icons. This code shows the first list item (the email icon) and the second list item (the Twitter icon) with the img class applied to it.

```
<div id="contact">
<ul>
<li class="menuimage">
<a target="_blank" href="mailto:david@davideyre.co.uk">
<img width="60" height="60" src="http://davideyre.co.uk/images/email_blue.png" data-other-src="http://davideyre.co.uk/images/emailblack.png">
</a>
</li>
<li class="menuimage">
<a target="_blank" href="http://twitter.com/davideyre">
<img class="qzsombkdzpaqphznltst" width="60" height="60" src="http://davideyre.co.uk/images/twitter_blue.png" data-other-src="http://davideyre.co.uk/images/twitterblack.png">
</a>
</li>
```

I have no idea how this img class is being applied to the images.

Comment: doesn't show up here. got any browser plugins that might be mangling your dom?

Comment: I tried to go you linked in image path and it's not found.

Comment: No classes are being added by my browsers.  Possibly plugin you have installed?

Comment: Let me guess, it only occurs on the social media icons? Disable your adblocker ;)

Answer (score 2):

Many thanks to MarkB, IAteYourKitten and Bondye. It was the Adblocker in Firefox. :)

Comment: Also your image http://davideyre.co.uk/image/linkedinblack.png is not loaded because it is not found [The requested URL /image/linkedinblack.png was not found on this server.] Check the name of permission of that file. :)

Answer (score 0):

I wonder why you are using the class `menuimage`. You don't use it in your CSS.

I would try adding some styling to the `menuimage` class in CSS to see if you can affect the styling of the list tag. Or remove the `menuimage` class from the list tag and add it to the image tag item, and try to add styling.

Comment: This is not an answer to the question. It should be a comment. I know you don't have rep to comment yet..